# Suggestions for strength workouts DVDs

Tags: workout, strength-training

In market, there are many cardio DVDs out there, to be done in Home or in Gym.
For example I like Insanity and 21 Day Fix. I have been doing cardio for 2 years.
 Now I want to introduce Strength training in my schedule, to have hybrid cardio/strength workouts.
 Any suggestion for good strength workouts DVDs for tuning body & losing fats ?

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Comment: It's a book, but it's terrific http://amzn.to/1Jxahve

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you skip the DVDs and get the [StrongLifts](http://stronglifts.com/) app. It's a beginners strength program and the app makes it super easy to follow. If you're just switching to strength training I'm certain you'll see some really nice gains the coming months.

Should you also want to keep your metcon up while using SL, then just throw in the odd Tabata workouts. Five minutes of intensive interval sprints will be more than enough.